# combining performing _.uniq with _.isEqual in lodash

Tags: lodash

lodash provides a method `_.uniq()` to find unique elements from an array, but the comparison function used is strict equality `===`, while I want to use `_.isEqual()`, which satisfies:

```
_.isEqual([1, 2], [1, 2])
// true
```

Is there a way to perform `_.uniq()` with `_.isEqual()`, without writing my own method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of lodash v4 there's `_.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual)`. 
from the docs:

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 },  { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
// → [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

more info: https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) with [uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq), what you're asking for seems perfectly reasonable and deserves a solution. Here's the best (clean/performant) I could come up with:

```js
_.reduce(coll, function(results, item) {
    return _.any(results, function(result) {
        return _.isEqual(result, item);
    }) ? results : results.concat([ item ]);
}, []);
```

You can use [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) to build an array of unique values. The [any()](https://lodash.com/docs#some) function uses `isEqual()` to check if the current item is already in the results. If not, it adds it.

Comment: there is no _.any function in current lodash, now there is _.some, if thats same as was _.any idk